# Drag mouse over controls to activate them?

Tags: c#

I have a question in my C# application. If You know the Novation launchpad, it has a 8x8 LED matrix button panel, and I just recreated them with gray panels which are code generated with two for loops:

```
for(int i=0;i<sizex;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<sizex;j++)
  {
    //Panel creation here
  }
}
```

Now if I create Click event handler for them, I am able to make a painting system (I want to change colors of the panels). But I want it like in real painting apps, that you can easily drag your mouse over some fields while holding the left mouse button to paint every panel which lies under the mouse.. The hover event did not work for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: Winforms, Wpf? And what's the reason of not working Hover event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MouseHover isn't going to be helpful, you'd have to hover the mouse for too long.  The non-intuitive thing you have to do is to turn off mouse capture in the panel's MouseDown event.  Required so the other panels still get mouse events.  Boilerplate code:

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    var panels = 8;
    var size = 20;
    var on = Color.Yellow;
    var off = Color.Black;
    for (int i = 0; i < panels; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < panels; j++) {
            var panel = new Panel() {
                Left = i * size, Top = j * size,
                Width = size, Height = size, BackColor = off
            };
            panel.MouseDown += (s, ea) => {
                panel.BackColor = panel.BackColor == on ? off : on;
                panel.Capture = false;
            };
            panel.MouseMove += (s, ea) => {
                if (ea.Button == MouseButtons.Left) panel.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            };
            this.Controls.Add(panel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So that would on one side work for clicks and moves right? I will try this out later!

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `drag&drop` approach:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int boardSize = 500;
        this.ClientSize = new Size(boardSize + 2, boardSize + 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                //New panel you can create like you want it
                //It's important to set AllowDrop = true!
                Panel p = new Panel
                {
                    Top = j * boardSize / 8,
                    Left = i * boardSize / 8,
                    Size = new Size(boardSize / 8 + 2, boardSize / 8 + 2),
                    AllowDrop = true,
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                };
                //This event will start DragDrop events
                p.MouseDown += (o, args) => ((Form)sender).DoDragDrop("", DragDropEffects.None);

                //Now you can change color of particual Panel
                p.DragOver += (o, args) => p.BackColor = Color.Blue;

                Controls.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Done something similar for a java (I'm aware that c# is not java) checkers game during college. I'm not sure if my answer will help you effectively, since I'm not giving you a clear code, and I don't have a hold of that java code anymore. But here's a brief description of the logic I used:

1. A stand by mode expects the mouse click;
2. Mouse click activates a logic which tracks where in the panel the mouse is hovering;
3. Painting code where the mouse hovered, possibly using some if-else
   logic to don't paint the same tile indefinitely;
4. Mouse release activates a logic which sets the program in stand by mode again.

I don't know which mouse handler you're using, but this might be helpful:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover(v=vs.110).aspx

I hope it helps you.